# How can I get the max value of SqlDbTypes like max SqlDbType.Int?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqldbtype

I would like to assign some string typed variables to MAximum values of some types in SQL Server 2008.

For example:

```
string foo = MaxValueInDbFor(SqlDbType.Int);
string boo = MaxValueInDbFor(SqlDbType.SmallInt);
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need this.

```
var maxValue =  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue;
var minValue =  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MinValue;
```

Same way you can get `Sql***.MaxValue` or `Sql***.MinValue` properties for any sql types .

Check out [System.Data.SqlTypes namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.